# Jquery Unobtrusive validation lost after implementing onSubmit event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. My validation works well until I attached an event to the form's onSubmit event.

This is how my form looks:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Recover", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "RecForm", onSubmit = "return Events.Submit(this,event)" }))
{
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        <input type="submit" value="Recover" />
}
```

The Javascript (works fine, just put it here so you can check if something in this is causing the validation not to fire):

```
//Events
window.Events = (function () {

    // Baseline setup
    var Events = {};

    function disableAllChildren(el) {
        $(el).find(':input').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    function enableAllChildren(el) {
        $(el).find(':input').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    //Ajax submit
    Events.Submit = function (el, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //serialize the form before disabling the elements.
        var data = $(el).serialize();

        disableAllChildren(el);
        $(el).find('.success, .error').hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: el.action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                //Stuff happens.
            }
        });
    };
    return Events;
})(this, this.document);
```

How do I get back my validations?

Comment: Doesn't `Events.Submit` completely overwrite the submit handler, taking ASP.NET out of the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is to check if the form is valid before I submit it. See the below code :

```
$form = $("#myForm");

if (form.valid()) {

    form.validate();
    //other codes here

 }
```

If the form is valid, then post your data. If not, do nothing.

Comment: Your $(el).valid() worked. Whats the point of form.validate() inside the check anyways?

Answer (score 1):

There're more problems in your code than validation. Case is that `disabled` fields do not get posted to server. They do not participate in validation either. So, even if your code worked, you would get nothing posted to server side. Remove `disableAllChildren(el);` or recode it to not *disable* fields, but maybe make them readonly.

With this, they will get validated, but not surprisingly **after the ajax submit**. This is behavior you should not wish, so take a look at [validate method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options). Especially you should be interested in part where it

> Submits the form via Ajax when valid.

I believe that way validated form ajax submission can be done easier.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
   }
})
```

Or, just add validation checking right before ajax submit

Comment: This is why I serialized the form into data var before disabling.