# Validation problems when using jQuery and Ajax to post back form in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having some challenges with validation in my ASP.NET MVC3 project when using jQuery and AJAX to post back data from a partial view.

Adding validation to the NoteText field within my partial view results in "$('#noteAdd').submit" event failing to trigger and my form posting directly to the controller.  Removing the validation results in the expected behaviour.

I was hoping somebody might be able to shed some light over what's happening here, why it's happening and my provide some advice on how to resolve the issue and I've included my partial, controller, JS and view below.

## My Partial

```
[Bind(Include = "NoteId,NoteText,Date,SourceId,Username,TypeId,ItemId,Processed")]
[MetadataType(typeof(NotePartial_Validation))]
public class NotePartial
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int? Source { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<NotePartial> ExistingNotes { get; set; }

}
public class NotePartial_Validation
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int NoteID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NoteText { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

}
```

}

## My Controller

```
public class NoteController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(NotePartial model)
    {

        try
        {
            NoteMethods.CreateNote(model.NoteText, SessionManager.Current.ActiveUser.Username, model.ItemId, SessionManager.Current.ActiveUser.Company);

            return Json(new { s = "Success" });
        }
        catch (NoPermissionException)
        {
            return Json(new { s = "No permission" }); 
        }

    }
}
```

## My View

```
@model EF.NotePartial
@{using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Note", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "noteAdd" }))
{ 

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.NoteText, new { @class = "note-input" })  //note-input
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoteText)     

<input type="submit" value="Send" /> 

}}
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
    $('#noteAdd').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('An error occured when processing this request:\r\n\r\n' + thrownError);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.s);
            }
        });
        // it is important to return false in order to  
        // cancel the default submission of the form 
        // and perform the AJAX call 
        return false;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put partial keyword on your class :

```
public partial class NotePartial
```

Comment: How I managed to miss that I have no idea :) Thanks. Do you have any other comments about the code? I'm relatively new to MVC and wondered if this way the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @Nick Well, one thing I can tell is that you do not need to put every single property inside your partial class which handles validations. Just put the ones that you need to validate.

Comment: Thanks - one thing about the code above. If validation fails, the form is still submitted. If it succeeds, the form is posted back and a JSON file is pushed to the browser. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Nick see this answer of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564991/jquery-unobtrusive-validation-lost-after-implementing-onsubmit-event/7565398#7565398

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I looked and have tried it but something is seriously wrong. I removed the .submit handler and added in onSubmit = "isValid()" on the form, always returning false and the form doesn't post if invalid, but posts if valid and returns a JSON file. I'm very confused!

Comment: @Nick well, it sounds like another separate issue. Put up a new question and I am sure you will be provided some answers.

Comment: Sounds like it! Reposted here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637583/strange-validation-problems-with-a-ajax-jquery-postback-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3982/discussion-between-nick-and-tugberk)