# Strange validation problems with a Ajax/jQuery postback in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having problems with an Ajax/jQuery postback in ASP.NET MVC 3.

- If validation *fails* on the code below, the expected result is given and the form does not post.
- If validation *succeeds*, the function below is not hit upon form submission and the form submits and returns a json file to the browser.

If anybody could shed some light on this, I'd appreciate it.

I've included my *partial*, *view* and *controller* below.

## My View

```
@model TheLayer.EF.NoteAddPartial

@{using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Note", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "noteAdd" }))
{ 

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Note_Text, new { @class = "note-input"  })  //note-input
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note_Text)     

<input type="submit" value="Send" /> 

}}
```

## My client side script (within the view)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $('#noteAdd').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).valid()) {
            alert('posting');
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('An error occured when processing this request:\r\n\r\n' + thrownError);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.s);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

## My Controller

```
public class NoteController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult Create(NoteAddPartial model)
    {
        try
        {
            NoteMethods.CreateLeadNote(model.Note_Text, SessionManager.Current.ActiveUser.Username, model.ItemId, SessionManager.Current.ActiveUser.Company);
            return Json(new { s = "Success" });
        }
        catch (NoPermissionException)
        {
            return Json(new { s = "No permission" }); 
        }

    }
}
```

## My Partial

```
namespace XX
{
/// <summary>
/// Partial lead person view
/// </summary>
[MetadataType(typeof(NoteAddPartial_Validation))]
public partial class NoteAddPartial
{
    public string Note_Text { get; set; }
    public int? Source { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

}
public class NoteAddPartial_Validation
{

    [Required]
    public string Note_Text { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: I have not been able to intercept the submit of a form when using unobtrusive validation. That is what you want to do, right? No matter if the form is valid or not, you want to intercept the `submit` event in your client-side javascript and do something. Making it clearer in the question may net you a good answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add client side validation libraries?

> jquery.validate.min.js
>
> jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

**NOTE :**

> If you configured you app not to work with unobtrusive validation, you
>   do not need to reference the second library.

Comment: I have both of these assets included.

Comment: $(this).valid() should work. do you catch any javascript errors. Check your browsers console for any.

Comment: This helped.  References for these were present in two places, both on a script manager and added manually by me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching to the `click` event on your submit button, and changing your code from `this` to a selector for the parent form for the button.